# Database design for book reader app

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to design a database using Postgresql for a book reader app.
Everything was ok until I get to the part of storing chapters.

Say there's 20,000 books, each books may have up to 2000 chapters. I couldn't think of anyway that's satisfying.

Right now my tables are like this:

BOOKS 
- id
- title
- cover_image
- views

BOOKS INFO (this is the detail info of a book)
- id
- title
- description
- author
- categories
...

DESIRED CHAPTER MODEL
- title
- content
- views

I'VE TRIED:
- To use custom type (or composite type in Postgres's term), which resulted to incorrect string format, data is badly saved, and it's just doesn't feel right.
- To use a Chapter table, everything is nicely stored to database. But the number of rows on Chapter table is too large (consider the average chapters in a book is 800). Also, I'm getting the chapters of a book by SELECT WHERE book_id = BOOKS.id. It's obviously won't scale.

Please help me guys.

P/s: I'm new to databases, please forgive me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is: will you need to work with Chapters separately from Books?
If you don't, then i assume you can create a column 'Chapter' of type JSON in BOOKS INFO table. And then you can store all Book Chapters in this column in JSON format. 
See this link: https://blog.codeship.com/unleash-the-power-of-storing-json-in-postgres/

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I'll try this

Answer (score 0):

From relational perspective you are forced to use a detail table like BookChapters with primary key the BookID and the ChpaterID. What i can propose for effective scaling is to separate the large data (content?) to a different table (BookChaptersContent? )related 1 to 1 with BookChapters. It will be like:
table Books (BookId, ...)PK (BookId)
table BookChapters (FK BookId, ChapterId, Title, Views)PK (BookId, ChapterId)
table BookChapterContent (FK BookId, FK ChapterId, Content)PK (BookId, ChapterId)
This will help keep row size of BookChapters small thus faster searched and most importantly isolates chapters from chapter contents as from Books you can join to either details table depending what you need to do. Practically this helps because when for example you browse a book you can read all chapters without their contents and then be able to query for a chapter content on demand. Another example is that when a content got updated (BookChapterContent ) the chapters are not affected by data update locks (BookChapters).

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning - "BookChapters" suggests that a chapter can belong to multiple books (it's usually used for many-to-many relationships). I also don't think row size is anywhere near as important as how many queries you need to do, and how likely you are to hit an index.

Comment: ... table BookChapters (FK BookId... this column contains a bookid, thus any row in BookChapters will belong to a single Books.BookID, but a row in Books may have multiple rows (chapters) into BookChapters as primary key here is composed of tow columns, PK (BookId, ChapterId).

Comment: Row size is a big story... anyway RDBMS are design to work vertically with millions (and billions) of rows. However it is different to have an average row size of few KB than few MB. That is why i proposed to split 1 to 1 to BookChaptersContent, to isolate there the bulk of data.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
In my case the content is kinda simple, so there is no need to make it a separate table

Answer (score 0):

> It's obviously won't scale.

Not necessarily.

What seems like a huge number for a human being (20.000 books with 800 chapters = 16.000.000 records) is trivial for a relational database engine like Postgres - as long as you can search by index.

So, if you create an index on book_id, your sample query `SELECT WHERE book_id = BOOKS.id` should scale to hundreds of millions of chapters - as long as you're not planning to scale to hundreds of millions of users.

In general, my rule for database optimization is to build the clean, relational model first, populate it with sample data, and see if it works; optimize it using indexes etc., add more hardware, and only look for alternatives once you can prove you have a problem.

Comment: This is the current design I'm using. However, in my case, the chapters are usually used together with BOOKINFO.
With this approach, whenever I show BOOKINFO, I'll have to run 2 queries - bookinfo, chapters - which is kinda a waste.
I'll try to store with json first, if that not working, then I'll index the book_id.